# Serializing Optional with Jackson: NON_ABSENT vs. configureAbsentsAsNulls and NON_NULL

Tags: json, serialization, null, jackson, option-type

When you want to serialize `Optional` with Jackson in Java, you must register the module `Jdk8Module`. This way, you either get the contained value or `null`.

Now if you also set serialization feature `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL`, I initially expected this to leave out both null-references and empty optionals from the JSON output as they both output `null` in the serialized JSON - but in fact it only leaves out the null-references. To also leave out the empty optionals, I found two options:

1. Set `configureAbsentsAsNulls(true)` on the `Jdk8Module`. According to the [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jdk8/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jdk8/Jdk8Module.html#configureAbsentsAsNulls-boolean-):

   > enabling means that Optional.empty() values are handled like Java
   >   nulls (wrt filtering on serialization); disabling that they are only
   >   treated as "empty" values, but not like native Java nulls. Recommended
   >   setting for this value is false. For compatibility with older versions
   >   of other "optional" values (like Guava optionals), it can be set to
   >   'true'. The default is false for backwards compatibility.
2. Set `setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)` on the `ObjectMapper`, which will do everything `NON_NULL` does, but according to the [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_ABSENT) will also leave out:

   > "absent" value of a referential type (like Java 8 Optional, or {link
   >   java.utl.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference}); that is, something that
   >   would not deference to a non-null value. This option is mostly used to
   >   work with "Optional"s (Java 8, Guava).

Now I'm trying to understand the implications and practical differences between option 1 and 2 above, as both gives the same result - that both null-references and empty optionals are not serialized.

What is the preferred option? And are the two option identical in practice?

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `configureAbsentsAsNulls(true)` is deprecated since the release of version `2.13`. The deprecation message of this method says:

> Since 2.13, no replacement, will be removed from Jackson 3.0 (when optional types will be part of core databind)

The full Javadoc gives a little more details:

> Configuration method that may be used to change configuration setting _cfgHandleAbsentAsNull: enabling means that `Optional.empty()` values are handled like Java nulls (wrt filtering on serialization); disabling that they are only treated as "empty" values, but not like native Java nulls. Recommended setting for this value is `false`. For compatibility with older versions of other "optional" values (like Guava optionals), it can be set to 'true'. The default is `false` for backwards compatibility.
>
> Note that in most cases it makes more sense to just use `NON_ABSENT` inclusion criteria for filtering out absent optionals; this setting is mostly useful for legacy use cases that predate version 2.6.